# Getting ajax posted data in laravel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/update',
    data: ['a','b','c'], 
    type: 'POST'
})
```

Controller:

```
$input = Input::all();
var_dump($input);
die();
```

Output:

```
0: 1
1: 0
```

I'm trying to post an array from ajax and get it in Laravel, unfortunately it's not working. There are no problems with CSRF. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: is your request hit the controller function ?

Comment: Yes, it does hit the controller fnc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your trying to send a js array so stringify it and send,

```
var data = {para : ['a','b','c'] };
$.ajax({
    url: '/update',
    data: JSON.stringify(data), 
    type: 'POST'
})
```

get the data in the controller,

```
$input = Input::json("para");
$firstElement = $input[0];     // prints a
$secondElement = $input[1];    // prints b
$thirdElement = $input[2];     // prints c
```

Comment: Nope, this outputs: 0: 3
1: 0
2: 1
3: 1
4: 1
5: 2
6: 1